# Get and store execution time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, execution-time

Is there a way to get and store the execution time of a select?

```
select * from table1
```

Thank you,
Radu.

Comment: In SQL*Plus, you can use `set timing on`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I prefer autotrace output to timing. Timing output is influenced by lots of factors.

Comment: I need to store the time in a table to analyse for later. What i need is to see the time to select all data from each view on my schema, and store the information on a table with (table_name, select_time).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides TIMING command to check the execution time taken for a query.

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-nonstandard.html#timing%20sql%20commands

Answer (score 0):

[Tom Kyte](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/08/evolution.html) has developed a pretty simple test harness called **[runstats](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551378329289980701)** that gives you great timing information.

Answer (score 0):

All SQL statements are stored in V$SQL, but they will age out eventually.  ELAPSED_TIME/EXECUTIONS will get you the average time to run the query.